# tabulate: define floatfmt for each column

Tags: python, format, tabulate

I am using tabulate 0.75 to generate LaTeX tables.
The function tabulate which generates my tables has a built-in function to format the input.
But I want to define the amount of decimals for every column itself. For e.g.

```
a      b
18.12  16
17.47  15
```

This is the built-in function (floatfmt=".2f") which works perfectly - but it acts on every column the same.

```
tabulate(tables[i], headers[i], numalign="center", tablefmt="latex_booktabs", floatfmt=".2f")
```

I am getting my data via

```
tables = [(list(zip(
                unumpy.nominal_values(dt),
                unumpy.nominal_values(U),
                unumpy.nominal_values(I),
                unumpy.nominal_values(E),
                unumpy.std_devs(E)))), ............and so on
```

I am using ufloat for my lists

```
array123 = ufloat(nominalvalues, errors)
```

very often because it makes handling with errors pretty easy. Does anyone know a simple way to format?

```
"{:.2f}".format(unumpy.nominal_values(E))
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

This doesnt work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: np.round(unumpy.nominal_values(E), x) did the job!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate):

> `floatfmt` argument can be a list or a tuple of format strings, one
>   per column, in which case every column may have different number
>   formatting::
>
> ```
> >>> print tabulate([[0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345]], floatfmt=(".1f", ".3f"))
> --- ----- -------
> 0.1 0.123 0.12345
> --- ----- -------
> ```

That should make your code a little neater.